# Python Edit a header value with urllib

Tags: python, header, urllib3

I am creating this request:

```
url="http://tn.ai/1244844"
response = self.http.request('GET', urllib.parse.quote(url, safe=':/?='), headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"})
```

Here I'm getting all headers:

```
response.getheaders()
```

Result is:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Location: =?utf-8?b?aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudGFzbmltbmV3cy5jb20vZmEvbmV3cy8xMzk1LzA4LzMwLzEyNDQ4NDQvw5nChsOawq/DmMKnw5nChy3DmMKow5jCrsOYwrTDm8KMLcOZ?=

Ø¨Ø§Ø±Ø²Ù-Ø¨Ø§-ÙØ§ÚØ§Ù-Ø±Ø§-Ù
Ø´Ú©Ù-Ú©Ø±Ø¯Ù-Ø§Ø³Øª
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Date: Sun, 20 Nov 2016 21:28:25 GMT
Content-Length: 253
```

Now, since i have some unknown values in `Location` value, i get this error in parsing header values:

```
Failed to parse headers (url=http://www.tasnimnews.com:80/fa/news/1395/08/30/1244844/%D9%86%DA%AF%D8%A7%D9%87-%D8%A8%D8%AE%D8%B4%DB%8C-%D9%85%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%B2%D9%87-%D8%A8%D8%A7-%D9%82%D8%A7%DA%86%D8%A7%D9%82-%D8%B1%D8%A7-%D9%85%D8%B4%DA%A9%D9%84-%DA%A9%D8%B1%D8%AF%D9%87-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA): [MissingHeaderBodySeparatorDefect()], unparsed data: 'Ø¨Ø§Ø±Ø²Ù\x87-Ø¨Ø§-Ù\x82Ø§Ú\x86Ø§Ù\x82-Ø±Ø§-Ù\x85Ø´Ú©Ù\x84-Ú©Ø±Ø¯Ù\x87-Ø§Ø³Øª\r\nServer: Microsoft-IIS/8.5\r\nDate: Sun, 20 Nov 2016 21:28:25 GMT\r\nContent-Length: 253\r\n\r\n'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 405, in _make_request
    assert_header_parsing(httplib_response.msg)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\response.py", line 59, in assert_header_parsing
    raise HeaderParsingError(defects=defects, unparsed_data=unparsed_data)
urllib3.exceptions.HeaderParsingError: [MissingHeaderBodySeparatorDefect()], unparsed data: 'Ø¨Ø§Ø±Ø²Ù\x87-Ø¨Ø§-Ù\x82Ø§Ú\x86Ø§Ù\x82-Ø±Ø§-Ù\x85Ø´Ú©Ù\x84-Ú©Ø±Ø¯Ù\x87-Ø§Ø³Øª\r\nServer: Microsoft-IIS/8.5\r\nDate: Sun, 20 Nov 2016 21:28:25 GMT\r\nContent-Length: 253\r\n\r\n'
```

What is the solution?

How can i prevent from this error?

Should i edit location value manually?

If yes, how?